# What's the best way to redirect an entire classic ASP website to a new domain?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I need to redirect an entire classic asp based website to a new domain whilst still maintaining the search engine ranking of the old site.

I think a 301 redirect is required but not sure what the best way of doing this would be as I don't think .htaccess works on an IIS Windows based server.

I would prefer not to have to change existing ASP files individually as there are quite a few.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know if there is a better method, but what I do is using IIS permanent redirect:

1. Go to the "Home Directory" tab of the site properties
2. Select option "A redirection to a URL"
3. Enter "http://yournewurl$S$Q" in the "Redirect to" text box
4. Check both the options "The exact URL entered above", and "A permanent redirection for this resource"

So all requests for `http://youroldurl/path/page?querystring` get permanently redirected to `http://yournewurl/path/page?querystring`

More details can be [found here](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55523).

PS: Above are steps for II6, IIS 7 might differ, I can't really recall.

Update:

Using 404 direct with the following in the default page and the 404 page:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://yournewurl/"
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I don't have access to the IIS properties as the site is on a shared hosted server.

Comment: @cyberbobcat: Do you have a current 404 handling page? If there is, you can use it to redirect all requests to your new site. Of course you have to move all other files away and modify the default page too. See my updated post.